# Regex with C# to remove matching prefix and suffix and leave partial

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not sure how to phrase my search to get what I need. I have instances of following lines in a large code base

```
$utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, 213)
$utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, itemId)
$utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, data.id)
```

I need to change them to

```
213
itemId
data.id
```

or in general, replace

```
dasf->fd.fer$%#tewqeqABCDE#@S$%D
dasf->fd.fer$%#tewqeqCDEF#@S$%D
dasf->fd.fer$%#tewqeqFGHITP#@S$%D
```

with

```
ABCDE
CDEF
FGHITP
```

The prefix and suffix are always related and always same. 
How can I form such pattern with regular expression in C#? I also like to know, what this kind of pattern matching is called?

**EDIT**

I tried this

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\$utils\\.decode\\(Coding\\.ASCII, (.*)\\)");
inStr = regex1.Replace(inStr, "$1");
```

But couldn't make it work

**EDIT**

This is an example for @Enigmativity

```
$item.save(
    $utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, 213),
    $utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, itemId),
    $utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, data.id),
    currDate(),
    $user
);

...

$item.get(
    $utils.encode(Coding.ASCII, 213),
    currDate(),
    $user
);

...

$item.calculatePrice(
    $utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, itemId)
);
```

in above text `$utils.decode(Coding.ASCII,` and `)` should be removed together.

Comment: Can you replace `\$utils\.decode\(Coding\.ASCII, (.*)\),` with `$1` - https://regex101.com/r/kC5oD4/1 ? Or do you somehow need something more general? Do you know your prefix and suffix?

Comment: Why don't you use normal string replace? We are talking about removing *fixed and known* substrings, after all.

Comment: @Kobi, Yes prefix and suffixes are always known and related but I have too many suffix + prefix cases to mention one by one so I asked for a general answer. Your Regex is working correctly but how I use it in C#?

Comment: @Tomalak, imagine this is part of a code that has multiple closed parenthesis, I cannot simply replace all occurrences of it, right? to make it clear, I shouldn't replace $utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, itemId, decodeType.TWO_BYTE),

Comment: I see, then regex is the way to go. I'm sure you will find an infinite number of examples that show you how to use regex in C#.

Comment: @BobSort - I've read you comment in response to Tomalak and you've made it less clear. Can you please provide a better example in your question as to why a simple `.Replace(...)` won't work?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I need to remove both suffix and prefix together. I have 38607 instances of matching the prefix. a simple replace cannot remove `)` only if there is a prefix of `$utils.decode(Coding.ASCII,`

Comment: @BobSort - Sorry, your example isn't clearing it up for me. Can you show a more complete example of your input data? Right now it looks a simple replace, or even substring, would work.

Comment: @BobSort - are you saying that there is a lot of other text that needs to stay there after the suffixes and prefixes are removed? So something like `AX(Y)B` => `AYB`?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I added an example for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var result =
    Regex
        .Replace(
            code,
            Regex.Escape("$utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, ")
                + "(.*?)"
                + Regex.Escape(")"),
            "$1");
```

So, from this:

```
    var code = @"$item.save( $utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, 213), $utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, itemId), $utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, data.id), currDate(), $user );

... $item.get( $utils.encode(Coding.ASCII, 213), currDate(), $user ); ...

$item.calculatePrice( $utils.decode(Coding.ASCII, itemId) );";
```

I got this:

```
$item.save( 213, itemId, data.id, currDate(), $user );

... $item.get( $utils.encode(Coding.ASCII, 213), currDate(), $user ); ...

$item.calculatePrice( itemId );
```

The `"(.*?)"` simply captures a groups of zero or more characters, but as few as possible. The downside to this is that it won't balance brackets, so this approach won't work if the argument inside the `$utils.decode` call has brackets.

Comment: It would be great to add an explanation about the pattern you are using. And one more thing is this pattern matching has a name?